# Python SnakeSQL Table not found error

Tags: python-2.7, web.py

I am learning Python and SnakeSQL for my database operations. I am following the examples of both web.py and SnakeSQL's. I combined both codes from their web sites and tried to make the below code worked but I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File ".\app.py", line 9, in 
>      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Test (dateColumn, numberColumn) VALUES ('2004->11-8', 4)")
>    File "D:\Python\virtualenvs\new4\textweb\bin\SnakeSQL\driver\base.py", line >1552, in execute
>      self.info = self.connection._insert(parsedSQL['table'], >parsedSQL['columns'], parsedSQL['sqlValues'], parameters)
>    File "D:\Python\virtualenvs\new4\textweb\bin\SnakeSQL\driver\base.py", line >1040, in _insert
>      raise SQLError("Table '%s' not found."%(table))
>   error.SQLError: Table 'Test' not found.

And here my app.py code:

```
import web
import SnakeSQL

render = web.template.render('templates/')
connection = SnakeSQL.connect(database='test', autoCreate=True)
connection = SnakeSQL.connect(database='test')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Test (dateColumn, numberColumn) VALUES ('2004-11-8', 4)")


urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self, name):
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Test")
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        return render.index(results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

What could be wrong in here?

Comment: The name of your database is "Test". You are connecting to it successfully.  But it seems there is no table called "Test" in the database.  Could it be that you are confusing the database name and the table name?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It solved my problem.